# Image view not changing/Shared prefs not updating (android)

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

My app utilizes a Image view that changes daily. It runs a receiver every 24 hours which should send a notification and change the shared preferences value (this being the image to display). The notification runs fine at the correct time so I know the receiver works correctly. When you launch the activity the image that needs to be changed is located, the app gets the shared preferences value and then sets the imageView to display that image. The default value is set to 0, and if the value is 0 it sets the image to a "something went wrong" style of image. How come the notification works but my image view doesn't change? It stays as the "something went wrong image"?

My code:

The Reciever:

```
    val quotes = arrayOf(R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3, R.drawable.i5, R.drawable.i6, R.drawable.i7, R.drawable.i8, R.drawable.i9, R.drawable.i10, R.drawable.i11, R.drawable.i12, R.drawable.i13, R.drawable.i14, R.drawable.i15, R.drawable.i16, R.drawable.i17, R.drawable.i18, R.drawable.i19, R.drawable.i20, R.drawable.i21, R.drawable.i22, R.drawable.i23, R.drawable.i24, R.drawable.i25)
    val quote = quotes.random()

    val prefquotes = context.getSharedPreferences("save", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    prefquotes.putInt("Quotes", quote)
    prefquotes.apply()
```

Qinsperation:

```
        val quote = sharedPreferences.getInt("Quote", 0)

        setContentView(R.layout.qinsperational)

        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.daily_image)

       if (quote == 0) {
           imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.oh_no)
       }else{
           Log.d("Quote", "good")
           imageView.setImageResource(quote)
       }
```

There is no crashes or anything in the logs. All help is much appreciated as I can't figure this one out

Comment: While saving you are using "Quotes" as key but while retrieving it is "Quote" (s is missing).

Comment: Also make sure you're using the same preferences file, called `"save"`, not the one you get by calling `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. The mismatched key string is a good example of why you should define a single constant somewhere, and reference that instead of typing the value out each time. Avoids bugs!

Comment: Thanks guys, Can't believe it was that simple lol. It works now!

Comment: I know it's a pain, but make it a rule for yourself never to pass a literal String to a function that takes a key. Use `const`s. It will save you a lot of time hunting down bugs like this in the long run.